# java.lang.NullPointerException JSP Servlet

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicação web utilizando jsp e servlet e quero mostrar todos os meus registros do meu banco de dados e a quantidade de registros em uma table, criei um DAO em que realizei as consultas em que retornam os dados corretamente e coloquei em uma sessão em uma servlet dando o nome de sessaoListaMotoristasTodos e totalMotorista mas ao passar os valores recuperados da sessão  e atribuir as variaveis, os valores não são atribuidos, as variaves chamadas são  `List  listaMotoristas` e `Integer totalRegistros` dando um erro de `java.lang.NullPointerException`

UPDATE

```
   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /listaMotoristas2.jsp at line 49

   46: 
   47: List  listaMotoristas=(List)  
   request.getSession().getAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos");
   48: Integer totalRegistros= (Integer)  
   request.getSession().getAttribute("totalMotorista");
   49: int totalPaginas=totalRegistros/limite;
   50: if(totalRegistros%limite!=0){
   51: totalPaginas++;
    52: }
 Stacktrace:

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrappe r.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.listaMotoristas2_jsp._jspService(listaMotoristas2_jsp.java:111)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

 public Integer totalRegistros(String pesquisa){

            try {
        con = Conecta.conexao();
       String sql="Select count(*) as contaRegistros from tb_motorista where mo_nome like '%"+pesquisa+"%'";
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();     

       ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql); 

        rs.next();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs.getString("contaRegistros"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("contaRegistros"));
        Integer 
      totalRegistros=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("contaRegistros"));
        return totalRegistros;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,e);

}
            return 0;
}



public List<Motoristas> mostrarMotoristas(){

    try { 
    con = Conecta.conexao();

       String sql="Select * from tb_motorista ";
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();     

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql); 
      List lista = new ArrayList(); 


        while(rs.next()){
             Motoristas mo= new Motoristas();
            mo.setMo_nome((rs.getString("mo_nome")));
            mo.setMo_data(rs.getString("mo_data"));
            mo.setMo_cpf(rs.getString("mo_cpf"));
            mo.setMo_modelo(rs.getString("mo_modelo"));
            mo.setMo_status(rs.getString("mo_status"));
            mo.setMo_sexo(rs.getString("mo_sexo"));


           lista.add(mo);

        }

        return lista;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,e);
        return null;
    }

}


       protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     MotoristasDAO dao= new MotoristasDAO();
         MotoristasDAO dao2= new MotoristasDAO();

   String pesquisa=request.getParameter("pesquisa");
     try {
     if(pesquisa==null){
    pesquisa="";
    } 


       Integer totalMotorista=dao.totalRegistros(pesquisa);
       request.setAttribute("totalMotoristas", totalMotorista);


           List listaMotoristas2=dao2.mostrarMotoristas();


          request.setAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos", dao2); 


     RequestDispatcher rd= 
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/listaMotoristas2.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na servelet"+e);
    }

     }

     <%
  List  listaMotoristas=(List) request.getAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos");
  Integer totalRegistros= (Integer) request.getAttribute("totalMotorista");
 int totalPaginas=totalRegistros/limite;
 if(totalRegistros%limite!=0){
 totalPaginas++;
 }
  else{
totalPaginas=0;
}
     %>
```

Comment: Adiciona a pilha de erros.

Comment: Duas coisas:
1. Adicione aqui a stack trace do erro para identificar o local especifico onde ele ocorre
2. Voce nāo deve utilizar biblioteca swing nas servlets pois nao vai funcionar, como aqui:
} catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,e);

}

Comment: A linha `con = Conecta.conexao();` funciona? Digo, a variável `con` deixa de ser nula depois da execução dessa linha?

Comment: Igor venturelli funciona perfeitamente, debuguei o codigo e os metodos que fazem a busca no banco de dados retornam os dados corretamente

Comment: dei um UPDATE na pergunta e coloquei o stack trace completo do erro

Answer (score 1):

Algumas observacoes:

- Adicione a stack trace do erro para identificar o local especifico onde ele ocorre, pois convenhamos fica muito dificil inferir;
- Voce nāo deve utilizar biblioteca swing nas servlets pois nao vai funcionar, como aqui:

  ```
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,e);
  ```
- Você nao deve utilizar dois blocos try..catch em um mesmo método da forma como esta fazendo, pois no primeiro, se ocorrer um erro de conexao com o banco ele vai "logar" o erro e continuar executando, ou seja, vai dar erro nas linhas subsequentes. Coloque tudo em unico bloco try..catch por favor.

Comment: coloquei o stack trace completo do erro, e deixei com apenas um try catch

Comment: mesmo deixando apenas um try catch o erro persistiou o mesmo

Comment: Sim, o try..catch unico nao resolveria o seu problema haja visto que o erro esta no seu arquivo JSP, linha 49. Possivelmente a variavel totalRegistros esta nula. Veja se voce esta retornando ela corretamente no response da Servlet

Comment: isso que eu estou perguntando cara, ao pegar a response da servlet ele não retorna o total de registros, sendo que debuguei o codigo das consultas do DAO e retornam os valores corretamente, sendo que estou pegando o nome da response da Servlet corretamente, não sei porque não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Você esta procurando pelo nome errado. Esta setando "totalMotoristas" plural.

```
request.setAttribute("totalMotoristas", totalMotorista);
```

E tentando recuperar como "totalMotorista" singular.

```
Integer totalRegistros= (Integer) request.getAttribute("totalMotorista");
```

Comment: mudei e coloquei no plural mas continuou o mesmo erro

Comment: ja debuguei o codigo varias vezes ele retorna o resultado do banco, mas quando eu atribuo o request.getAttribute("") a Interger totalRegistros ele fica null

Comment: Alguma coisa esta errada com o codigo do stack trace, pois esta diferente do codigo que voce postou aqui. No do stack trace voce esta tentando pegar o valor da sessao (request.getSession().getAttribute(...)). Esta confuso.